# References numeration in beamer

Tags: beamer

How to get the corresponding index citation also in the bibliography? It appears in the main text but not in the given References.

Note: I tried it manually with the \footnote command but then instead of a number, appears a letter.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
This is my reference \cite{A}.
\par\noindent\rule{5cm}{0.4pt} 
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{A} {\tiny Author 
                \newblock \emph{Title}
                \newblock Journal (2021).}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to keep the minimum example minimal. Most of the showed code  is irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
```

or ...

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
```

... that is better in case that you use custom labels like `\bibitem[foo]{SK}` whereas the former is better in case that you want to change the squared brackets in the references.

MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\arabic{enumiv}]} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Foo \cite{SK} and \cite{AB}.
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{AB} This is AB  reference ...
\bibitem{SK} This is SK reference  ...
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked out (thanks!), but i used two references in different frames and they shown the same numeration [1] in both them. I would like them to be displayed in the properly order (the one of the first frame with [1] and the one on the other frame with [2]) Can you help me?

Comment: @lcruzt  If you have [1] twice because you used the same cite twice. The number of  the cite is not  the order of appearing each cite in the text of the frames,  but the order of appearing in the references.  For the same reason, the SK and AB cites are  "[2] and [1]" instead of "[1] and [2]". If you want all the cites ordered, then the `\bibitem`s  should  not be ordered an alphabetic but by the citation order, ... and never cite more than once.

Comment: I have not used the same cite twice, but different citation labels in each occurrence. The thing is they appear in different frames... for example, in frame 1 I cited {AA} and got [1], but in frame 2 I cited {BB} and got also [1] instead of [2], so it seems in the second one they satarts again in "[1]". Please, see the example in the next comment.

Comment: \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} \begin{frame}
1st frame with first \cite{A} and second \cite{B} references
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{A} A authors \newblock \emph{ first title}\newblock first journal.
\bibitem{B} B authors \newblock \emph{ second title}\newblock second journal.\end{thebibliography} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} 2nd frame with 3rd reference \cite{C}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{C} C authors \newblock \emph{ third title}\newblock third journal.
\end{thebibliography} \end{frame}

Comment: OK, but you have used `thebibliography` twice, resenting the counter: Options: (a) Do not do that (recommended) and use it only once in the last frame,  or (b) set manually the counter after every reset (`\setcounter{enumiv}{2}\bibitem{C} ...`),  or (c) fix the label for each cite (`\bibitem[whatever]{C}`)  or maybe (d) switch to `biblatex` and use `\footfullcite.`